# DHL Rate calculation

Tags: php

In my website(php based) I want implement a rate calculator of DHL. I want to add 3 fields-1.Origin, 2.Destination and 3.Weight. These 3 values will be sent to DHL server and in return I want to have the RATE. How can I do that?

In another section, I will add more field (address, product hts code, etc.) with those 3 to get the RATE. How can it be done also??

Comment: Do you have access to any DHL API?

Comment: I recommend you to sign up for access to their XML API:
http://www.dhl-usa.com/xml/index.asp

Comment: No, I don't have the access. How can I get access?

Answer (score 8):

Below is DHL rate calculator code: You need to change siteid and password with your DHL siteid and password.

```
<?php
$data = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<p:DCTRequest xmlns:p="http://www.dhl.com" xmlns:p1="http://www.dhl.com/datatypes" xmlns:p2="http://www.dhl.com/DCTRequestdatatypes" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.dhl.com DCT-req.xsd ">
  <GetQuote>
    <Request>
      <ServiceHeader>
        <MessageTime>'.date('c').'</MessageTime>
        <MessageReference>1234567890123456789012345678901</MessageReference>
        <SiteID>YOUR_DHL_SITE_ID</SiteID>
        <Password>YOUR_DHL_PASSWORD</Password>
      </ServiceHeader>
    </Request>
    <From>
        <CountryCode>GB</CountryCode>
        <Postalcode>WC1A</Postalcode>
    </From>
    <BkgDetails>
      <PaymentCountryCode>US</PaymentCountryCode>
      <Date>2011-06-06</Date>
      <ReadyTime>PT10H21M</ReadyTime>
            <ReadyTimeGMTOffset>+01:00</ReadyTimeGMTOffset>
            <DimensionUnit>CM</DimensionUnit>

            <WeightUnit>KG</WeightUnit>
            <Pieces><Piece>
                <PieceID>1</PieceID>
                <Height>20</Height>
                <Depth>20</Depth>
                <Width>20</Width>   
                <Weight>19</Weight>
            </Piece></Pieces>
            <IsDutiable>N</IsDutiable>
            <NetworkTypeCode>AL</NetworkTypeCode>
        </BkgDetails>
        <To>
            <CountryCode>US</CountryCode>
            <Postalcode>10101</Postalcode>
        </To>       
    </GetQuote>
</p:DCTRequest>';
$tuCurl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($tuCurl, CURLOPT_URL, "https://xmlpitest-ea.dhl.com/XMLShippingServlet");
curl_setopt($tuCurl, CURLOPT_PORT , 443);
curl_setopt($tuCurl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 0);
curl_setopt($tuCurl, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($tuCurl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($tuCurl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($tuCurl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
curl_setopt($tuCurl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: text/xml","SOAPAction: \"/soap/action/query\"", "Content-length: ".strlen($data)));

$tuData = curl_exec($tuCurl);

curl_close($tuCurl);
$xml = simplexml_load_string($tuData);
print "<pre>";
print_r($xml);
?>
```

For more reference click on below link:

http://xmlpitest-ea.dhl.com/serviceval/jsps/main/Main_menu.jsp

Comment: How would I do this with <IsDutiable>Y</IsDutiable> ?